# Change SP 2013 "Add a Page" link to create a Wiki Page in the Pages library rather than a Site Page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

I have a Team Site collection which has the Publishing features enabled. When I click on the Site Settings icon and select "Add a Page" it always wants to create a site page under the "Site Pages" library.  How can I change this default to a wiki page under the "Pages" library?

I've already limited the Page Layout and New Page Default Settings under the Site Settings / Page Layout and Site Template Settings but it doesn't seem to have effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get this working you need to go to

Site settings >> Manage site features - Find Site Pages feature, Deactivate it (Don't worry this won't delete your site pages library)

now try clicking "Add a Page"

[image: Add a Page]

To get a wiki as default change default content type of your Document library to Wiki

Comment: Thanks, I don't see a Site Pages feature under either the Manage Site Features or the Site Collection Features.  Do you know if it's part of another feature?

Comment: I searched and found that "Site Pages" are part of the "Wiki Page Home Page" feature.  I disabled it and it seems to do the trick.  Thanks!

Comment: i know this is 2 years old, but I have been searching for this exact answer for DAYS!  took so many different ways of constructing a google search to find this answer.  TYVM